# Linked server SQL Server to Oracle not returning data

Tags: sql-server, oracle, openquery

i have a stored procedure in SQL Server like this:

```
DECLARE @EFEKTIF_DATE VARCHAR(15);
SET @EFEKTIF_DATE = (SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE),106),' ','-') EFEKTIF_DATE)

DECLARE @SQL_P1 VARCHAR(MAX) = 
'SELECT   papf.employee_number , 
         papf.original_date_of_hire , 
         paaf.effective_start_date , 
         paaf.person_id , 
         ppt.user_person_type , 
         ppt.person_type_id , 
         paaf.assignment_id , 
         paaf.organization_id , 
         papf.last_name , 
         papf.sex code_jk , 
         papf.marital_status , 
         '''+@EFEKTIF_DATE+''' efektif_date , 
         CASE 
            WHEN Upper(Nvl(amdtl.user_status , sttl.user_status)) LIKE ''ACTIVE%'' and ppt.user_person_type<>''Ex-employee'' THEN ''ACTIVE'' 
                  ELSE ''RESIGN'' 
         END user_status , 
         Decode(paaf.assignment_type , ''E'' , (select meaning from hr_lookups where lookup_type = ''EMP_CAT'' and lookup_code = paaf.employment_category),
         ''C'', (select meaning from hr_lookups where lookup_type = ''CWK_ASG_CATEGORY'' and lookup_code = paaf.employment_category)) assignment_category ,          
         (select meaning from    hr_lookups  where   lookup_type     = ''EMPLOYEE_CATG''
        and lookup_code = paaf.employee_category) employee_category , 
         papf.date_of_birth tgl_lahir , 
         papf.town_of_birth tempat_lahir , 
         (SELECT meaning 
                FROM   fnd_lookup_values 
                WHERE  lookup_type = ''BI_OM_PANGKAT'' 
                AND    pgd.segment2 = lookup_code) pangkat , 
         (SELECT NAME 
                FROM   per_jobs 
                WHERE  job_id = paaf.job_id) jabatan , 
         id_hridcommutil_pk.get_lookup_meaning(''BI_PA_PERSONAL_BRANDING'' , 
         (SELECT MAX(pac.segment1) 
                FROM   per_analysis_criteria PAC , 
                       per_person_analyses PPA 
                WHERE  paaf.person_id = ppa.person_id(+) 
                AND    pac.analysis_criteria_id(+) = ppa.analysis_criteria_id 
                AND 
                       (SELECT id_flex_num 
                              FROM   fnd_id_flex_structures_vl 
                              WHERE  id_flex_structure_code = ''BI_PA_PERSONAL_BRANDING'') = ppa.id_flex_num 
                AND paaf.effective_end_date BETWEEN ppa.date_from AND nvl(ppa.date_to , to_date(''31-DEC-4712'',''DD-MON-YYYY'')))) personal_branding , 
         nvl(to_date(pac_v.segment4 , ''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS''), papf.original_date_of_hire) tanggal_masuk_bi , 
         NULLIF (floor(months_between( LEAST( case when ppt.person_type_id=1130 and pac_v.segment1 is null then term.end_date+1 when to_date(pac_v.segment1,''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'')<nvl(to_date(pac_v.segment4,''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS''),papf.original_date_of_hire) then term.end_date+1 else to_date(nvl(pac_v.segment1,''4712/12/31 00:00:00''),''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'') end , '''+@EFEKTIF_DATE+''' ) + 1, nvl(to_date(pac_v.segment4 , ''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS''), papf.original_date_of_hire)) / 12)
                  || '' Tahun '' 
                  || round(mod(months_between( LEAST( case when ppt.person_type_id=1130 and pac_v.segment1 is null then term.end_date+1 when to_date(pac_v.segment1,''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'')<nvl(to_date(pac_v.segment4,''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS''),papf.original_date_of_hire) then term.end_date+1 else to_date(nvl(pac_v.segment1,''4712/12/31 00:00:00''),''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'') end , '''+@EFEKTIF_DATE+''' ) + 1 , nvl(to_date(pac_v.segment4 , ''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS''), papf.original_date_of_hire)) , 12))
                  || '' Bulan'' , '' Tahun  Bulan'') masa_dinas_bi , 
         to_date(pac_v.segment7 , ''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'') tanggal_satker , 
         NULLIF (floor(months_between( LEAST( case when ppt.person_type_id=1130 and pac_v.segment1 is null then term.end_date+1 when to_date(pac_v.segment1,''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'')<nvl(to_date(pac_v.segment4,''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS''),papf.original_date_of_hire) then term.end_date+1 else to_date(nvl(pac_v.segment1,''4712/12/31 00:00:00''),''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'') end , '''+@EFEKTIF_DATE+''' ) + 1 , to_date(pac_v.segment7 , ''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'')) / 12)
                  || '' Tahun '' 
                  || round(mod(months_between( LEAST( case when ppt.person_type_id=1130 and pac_v.segment1 is null then term.end_date+1 when to_date(pac_v.segment1,''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'')<nvl(to_date(pac_v.segment4,''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS''),papf.original_date_of_hire) then term.end_date+1 else to_date(nvl(pac_v.segment1,''4712/12/31 00:00:00''),''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'') end , '''+@EFEKTIF_DATE+''' ) + 1 , to_date(pac_v.segment7 , ''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'')) , 12))
                  || '' Bulan'' , '' Tahun  Bulan'') masa_dinas_satker , 
         to_date(pac_v.segment8 , ''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'') tanggal_jabatan , 
         NULLIF (floor(months_between( LEAST( case when ppt.person_type_id=1130 and pac_v.segment1 is null then term.end_date+1 when to_date(pac_v.segment1,''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'')<nvl(to_date(pac_v.segment4,''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS''),papf.original_date_of_hire) then term.end_date+1 else to_date(nvl(pac_v.segment1,''4712/12/31 00:00:00''),''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'') end , '''+@EFEKTIF_DATE+''' ) + 1 , to_date(pac_v.segment8 , ''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'')) / 12)
                  || '' Tahun '' 
                  || round(mod(months_between( LEAST( case when ppt.person_type_id=1130 and pac_v.segment1 is null then term.end_date+1 when to_date(pac_v.segment1,''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'')<nvl(to_date(pac_v.segment4,''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS''),papf.original_date_of_hire) then term.end_date+1 else to_date(nvl(pac_v.segment1,''4712/12/31 00:00:00''),''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'') end , '''+@EFEKTIF_DATE+''' ) + 1 , to_date(pac_v.segment8 , ''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'')) , 12))
                  || '' Bulan'' , '' Tahun  Bulan'') masa_dinas_jabatan , 
         to_date(pac_v.segment6 , ''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'') tanggal_pangkat , 
         NULLIF (floor(months_between( LEAST( case when ppt.person_type_id=1130 and pac_v.segment1 is null then term.end_date+1 when to_date(pac_v.segment1,''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'')<nvl(to_date(pac_v.segment4,''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS''),papf.original_date_of_hire) then term.end_date+1 else to_date(nvl(pac_v.segment1,''4712/12/31 00:00:00''),''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'') end , '''+@EFEKTIF_DATE+''' ) + 1 , to_date(pac_v.segment6 , ''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'')) / 12)
                  || '' Tahun '' 
                  || round(mod(months_between( LEAST( case when ppt.person_type_id=1130 and pac_v.segment1 is null then term.end_date+1 when to_date(pac_v.segment1,''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'')<nvl(to_date(pac_v.segment4,''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS''),papf.original_date_of_hire) then term.end_date+1 else to_date(nvl(pac_v.segment1,''4712/12/31 00:00:00''),''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'') end , '''+@EFEKTIF_DATE+''' ) + 1 , to_date(pac_v.segment6 , ''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'')) , 12))
                  || '' Bulan'' , '' Tahun  Bulan'') masa_dinas_pangkat , 
         nvl(floor(months_between(to_date(pac_v.segment1, ''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'') + 1 , LEAST( case when ppt.person_type_id = 1130 and pac_v.segment1 is null then term.end_date+1 else to_date(pac_v.segment1, ''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'') end , '''+@EFEKTIF_DATE+''' ) ) / 12) , 0) 
                  || '' Tahun '' 
                  || nvl(round(mod(months_between(to_date(pac_v.segment1, ''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'') + 1 , LEAST( case when ppt.person_type_id = 1130 and pac_v.segment1 is null then term.end_date+1 else to_date(pac_v.segment1, ''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'') end , '''+@EFEKTIF_DATE+''' ) ) , 12)) , 0) 
                  || '' Bulan'' sisa_masa_dinas ,
         to_date(pac_v.segment3 , ''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'') tanggal_mpp ,'
DECLARE @SQL_P2 VARCHAR(MAX)=
' 
         (SELECT meaning 
                FROM   fnd_lookup_values 
                WHERE  lookup_code = papf.attribute4 
                AND    lookup_type = ''BI_PA_JALUR_REKRUTMEN'') jalur_rekrutmen , 
         haou.attribute2 rubrik , 
         id_hridcommutil_pk.get_organization_name(haou.attribute8) satker , 
         id_hridcommutil_pk.get_organization_name(haou.attribute9) grup , 
         id_hridcommutil_pk.get_organization_name(haou.attribute10) divisi , 
         id_hridcommutil_pk.get_organization_name(haou.attribute11) tim , 
         id_hridcommutil_pk.get_organization_name(haou.attribute12) unit , 
         (SELECT location_code 
                FROM   hr_locations 
                WHERE  location_id = paaf.location_id) lokasi , 
         CASE 
                  WHEN papf.sex = ''F'' THEN ''Perempuan'' 
                  WHEN papf.sex = ''M'' THEN ''Laki-laki'' 
                  ELSE '' '' 
         END jenis_kelamin , 
         (SELECT hl.meaning 
                FROM hr_lookups hl 
                WHERE papf.per_information2 = hl.lookup_code 
                AND hl.enabled_flag = ''Y'' 
                AND hl.lookup_type = ''HR_ID_RELIGION'' 
                AND rownum = 1) agama , 
         hl2.meaning status_pernikahan , 
         (SELECT pac.segment3 
                FROM per_analysis_criteria pac , 
                       per_person_analyses ppa 
                WHERE paaf.person_id = ppa.person_id(+) 
                AND pac.analysis_criteria_id(+) = ppa.analysis_criteria_id 
                AND(SELECT id_flex_num 
                              FROM   fnd_id_flex_structures_vl 
                              WHERE  id_flex_structure_code = ''ID_EE_NPWP_TAX_DETAILS'') = ppa.id_flex_num 
                AND paaf.effective_end_date BETWEEN ppa.date_from AND    nvl(ppa.date_to , to_date(''31-DEC-4712'' , ''DD-MON-YYYY''))) tax_material_status , 
         (SELECT hl3.meaning 
                FROM hr_lookups hl3 
                WHERE papf.per_information3 = hl3.lookup_code 
                AND hl3.enabled_flag = ''Y'' 
                AND hl3.lookup_type = ''HR_ID_ETHNIC_ORIGIN'' 
                AND rownum = 1) suku_bangsa , 
         (SELECT meaning 
                FROM fnd_lookup_values 
                WHERE lookup_type = ''BI_OM_KOTA'' 
                AND attribute6 = ''Y'' 
                AND papf.attribute3 = lookup_code 
                AND rownum = 1) homebase , 
         (SELECT meaning 
                FROM fnd_lookup_values 
                WHERE lookup_type = ''BI_OM_PROVINSI'' 
                AND attribute1 = ''ID'' 
                AND papf.per_information10 = lookup_code) putra_daerah , 
         papf.email_address email_kantor , 
         case when ppt.person_type_id = 1130 and pac_v.segment1 is null then term.end_date+1
         when to_date(pac_v.segment1 , ''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'') < nvl(to_date(pac_v.segment4 , ''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS''), papf.original_date_of_hire) then term.end_date+1
         else to_date(pac_v.segment1 , ''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'') end      tanggal_pensiun , 
         case when ppt.person_type_id = 1130 then term.end_date+1 else null end       tanggal_berhenti ,
         pqt.NAME jenjangpendidikan , 
         round(nk_rata.performance_rating , 2) nk_rata_rata , 
         nk_.nk5 nk_4_thn , 
         nk_.nk4 nk_3_thn , 
         nk_.nk3 nk_2_thn , 
         nk_.nk2 nk_1_thn , 
         nk_.nk1 nk_terakhir , 
         nk_data.NK NK_ALL,
         CASE 
                  WHEN sanksi.cek = ''Y'' THEN ''YES'' 
                  ELSE ''NO'' 
         END sanksi , 
         CASE
            WHEN(SELECT meaning 
                                  FROM   fnd_lookup_values 
                                  WHERE  lookup_code = paaf.ass_attribute2 
                                  AND    lookup_type = ''BI_PA_JENIS_PERUBAHAN'') = ''Promosi Penghargaan'' THEN ''YES'' 
                  ELSE ''NO'' 
         END promosi , 
         CASE 
                  WHEN(SELECT pac.segment2 
                                  FROM   per_analysis_criteria pac , 
                                         per_person_analyses ppa 
                                  WHERE  paaf.person_id = ppa.person_id(+) 
                                  AND    pac.analysis_criteria_id(+) = ppa.analysis_criteria_id 
                                  AND(SELECT id_flex_num 
                                                FROM   fnd_id_flex_structures_vl 
                                                WHERE  id_flex_structure_code = ''BI_PA_IKATAN_DINAS'') = ppa.id_flex_num 
                                  AND paaf.effective_end_date BETWEEN ppa.date_from AND    nvl(ppa.date_to , to_date(''31-DEC-4712'' , ''DD-MON-YYYY'')) 
                                  AND rownum = 1) IS NOT NULL THEN ''YES'' 
                  ELSE ''NO'' 
         END status_ikatan_dinas , 
         CASE 
                  WHEN(SELECT ''Y'' 
                                  FROM   per_person_analyses pac , 
                                         fnd_id_flex_structures_vl f 
                                  WHERE  pac.id_flex_num = f.id_flex_num 
                                  AND    pac.person_id = papf.person_id 
                                  AND    f.id_flex_structure_code = ''BI_PA_MPP'' 
                                  AND    '''+@EFEKTIF_DATE+''' BETWEEN pac.date_from AND    nvl(pac.date_to , ''31-DEC-4712'') 
                                  AND    rownum = 1) IS NOT NULL THEN ''YES'' 
                  ELSE ''NO'' 
         END mengajukan_mpp ,
         (SELECT count (distinct CONTACT_PERSON_ID)
        FROM PER_CONTACT_RELATIONSHIPS pcr, HR_LOOKUPS hl
       WHERE pcr.person_id = paaf.person_id
             AND hl.LOOKUP_TYPE = ''CONTACT''
             AND hl.lookup_code LIKE ''BI_A%''
             AND hl.lookup_code NOT IN (''BI_A'', ''BI_AM'')
             AND hl.lookup_code = pcr.contact_type )   jumlah_anak , 
        (SELECT COUNT (*)
        FROM PER_CONTACT_RELATIONSHIPS pcr, HR_LOOKUPS hl
       WHERE     pcr.person_id = paaf.person_id
             AND hl.LOOKUP_TYPE = ''CONTACT''
             AND hl.lookup_code LIKE ''BI_A%''
             AND hl.lookup_code NOT IN (''BI_A'', ''BI_AM'')
             AND hl.lookup_code = pcr.contact_type
             AND pcr.dependent_flag = ''Y''
             AND '''+@EFEKTIF_DATE+''' BETWEEN TRUNC (date_start)
             AND NVL (TRUNC (date_end), ''31-DEC-4712'') )  jumlah_anak_ditanggung
FROM per_people_f papf , 
     per_person_types ppt , 
         (SELECT * 
                FROM (SELECT paaf.* , 
                                     final_process_date , 
                                     CASE 
                                            WHEN pps.final_process_date = paaf.effective_end_date 
                                            AND NVL((SELECT DISTINCT ''Y'' FROM PER_PERIODS_OF_SERVICE PPOS WHERE PERSON_ID = paaf.person_id AND DATE_START > paaf.effective_end_date), ''N'') = ''N'' THEN to_date(''31-DEC-4712'' , ''DD-MON-YYYY'') 
                                            ELSE paaf.effective_end_date 
                                     END effective_end_date1 
                              FROM   per_assignments_f paaf , 
                                     per_periods_of_service pps 
                              WHERE  pps.period_of_service_id = paaf.period_of_service_id 
                              AND paaf.person_id = pps.person_id) a 
                WHERE  '''+@EFEKTIF_DATE+''' BETWEEN a.effective_start_date AND a.effective_end_date1) paaf , 
         per_grades pg , 
         per_grade_definitions pgd , 
         hr_organization_units haou , 
         hr_lookups hl2 , 
         per_assignment_status_types st , 
         per_assignment_status_types_tl sttl , 
         per_ass_status_type_amends amd , 
         per_ass_status_type_amends_tl amdtl , 
         (SELECT * 
                FROM (SELECT ppa.person_id , 
                                     ppa.creation_date ppa_creation_date , 
                                     pac.* 
                              FROM   per_person_analyses ppa , 
                                     per_analysis_criteria pac ,         -- fixing
                                     (SELECT   ppa1.person_id, ppa1.date_from, max(ppa1.creation_date) creation_date
                                              FROM     per_person_analyses ppa1 
                                              INNER JOIN fnd_id_flex_structures_vl f on ppa1.id_flex_num = f.id_flex_num   AND      f.id_flex_structure_code = ''BI_PA_TANGGAL_KEPEGAWAIAN'' 
                                              LEFT JOIN (select person_id, date_from from per_person_analyses p INNER JOIN fnd_id_flex_structures_vl g on p.id_flex_num = g.id_flex_num AND g.id_flex_structure_code = ''BI_PA_TANGGAL_KEPEGAWAIAN'') ppa2
                                              on ppa2.person_id = ppa1.person_id and ppa2.date_from > ppa1.date_from
                                              where      ppa1.date_from <= '''+@EFEKTIF_DATE+''' and ppa2.person_id is null
                                              GROUP BY ppa1.person_id, ppa1.date_from ) ppa_v 
                              WHERE  1 = 1 
                              AND pac.analysis_criteria_id = ppa.analysis_criteria_id 
                              AND pac.id_flex_num = ppa.id_flex_num 
                              AND pac.enabled_flag = ''Y'' 
                              AND (SELECT id_flex_num 
                                            FROM   fnd_id_flex_structures_vl 
                                            WHERE  id_flex_structure_code = ''BI_PA_TANGGAL_KEPEGAWAIAN'') = ppa.id_flex_num 
                              AND    ppa.person_id = ppa_v.person_id 
                              AND    ppa.date_from = ppa_v.date_from 
                              AND    ppa.creation_date = ppa_v.creation_date)) pac_v ,'
DECLARE @SQL_P3 VARCHAR(MAX) = 
' 
         (SELECT   max(attribute1) attribute1 , 
                           person_id 
                  FROM    (SELECT to_number(qut.attribute1) attribute1 , 
                                         decode(qua.person_id , NULL , esa.person_id , qua.person_id) person_id 
                                  FROM   per_qualifications qua , 
                                         per_establishment_attendances esa , 
                                         per_establishments est , 
                                         hr.per_qualification_types qut 
                                  WHERE  qua.attendance_id = esa.attendance_id(+) 
                                  AND    esa.establishment_id = est.establishment_id(+) 
                                  AND    qut.qualification_type_id = qua.qualification_type_id) 
                  GROUP BY person_id) pend , 
         hr.per_qualification_types pqt , 
         (SELECT ''Y'' cek , 
                       person_id 
                FROM (SELECT ppa.person_id , 
                                     ppa.creation_date ppa_creation_date , 
                                     pac.* 
                              FROM   per_person_analyses ppa , 
                                     per_analysis_criteria pac ,         -- fixing
                                     (SELECT   ppa1.person_id, ppa1.date_from, max(ppa1.creation_date) creation_date
                                              FROM     per_person_analyses ppa1
                                              INNER JOIN fnd_id_flex_structures_vl f on ppa1.id_flex_num = f.id_flex_num AND f.id_flex_structure_code = ''BI_PA_SANKSI'' 
                                              LEFT JOIN (select person_id, date_from from per_person_analyses p INNER JOIN fnd_id_flex_structures_vl g on p.id_flex_num = g.id_flex_num AND g.id_flex_structure_code = ''BI_PA_SANKSI'') ppa2
                                              on ppa2.person_id = ppa1.person_id and ppa2.date_from > ppa1.date_from
                                              where '''+@EFEKTIF_DATE+''' BETWEEN ppa1.date_from AND nvl(ppa1.date_to , ''31-DEC-4712'')  and ppa2.person_id is null
                                              GROUP BY ppa1.person_id, ppa1.date_from ) ppa_v 
                              WHERE  1 = 1 
                              AND    pac.analysis_criteria_id = ppa.analysis_criteria_id 
                              AND    pac.id_flex_num = ppa.id_flex_num 
                              AND    pac.enabled_flag = ''Y'' 
                              AND(SELECT id_flex_num 
                                            FROM fnd_id_flex_structures_vl 
                                            WHERE id_flex_structure_code = ''BI_PA_SANKSI'') = ppa.id_flex_num 
                              AND ppa.person_id = ppa_v.person_id 
                              AND ppa.date_from = ppa_v.date_from 
                              AND ppa.creation_date = ppa_v.creation_date)) sanksi ,
         (SELECT * 
                FROM (SELECT person_id , 
                                     performance_rating , 
                                     row_num 
                              FROM (SELECT rownum row_num , yr 
                                            FROM (SELECT to_char(dt , ''yyyy'') yr 
                                                            FROM (SELECT to_date(''31-DEC-'' 
                                                                                          || 
                                                                                   (SELECT max(thn) 
                                                                                          FROM   apps.xxcust_nk_v) , ''DD-MON-YYYY'') - level dt 
                                                                            FROM dual connect BY level <= to_date(''31-DEC-'' 
                                                                                          || substr(to_char(trunc(sysdate) , ''MON-RRRR'') , 5 , 4) , ''DD-MON-YYYY'') - to_date(''01-JAN-'' 
                                                                                          ||(substr(to_char(trunc(sysdate) , ''MON-RRRR'') , 5 , 4) - 4) , ''DD-MON-YYYY'')) 
                                                            GROUP BY to_char(dt , ''yyyy'') 
                                                            ORDER BY to_char(dt , ''yyyy'') DESC)) tahun ,  
                                     apps.xxcust_nk_v nk 
                              WHERE tahun.yr = nk.thn(+)) PIVOT(max(performance_rating) FOR row_num IN(1 nk1 , 
                                                                                                        2 nk2 , 
                                                                                                        3 nk3 , 
                                                                                                        4 nk4 , 
                                                                                                        5 nk5))) nk_ ,
         (SELECT person_id, LISTAGG(thn || '':'' || performance_rating, '';'') within group (order by thn desc) NK
                  FROM apps.xxcust_nk_v
                  GROUP by person_id) nk_data,
         (SELECT person_id ,avg(performance_rating) performance_rating 
                  FROM (SELECT rownum row_num,yr 
                                  FROM (SELECT to_char(dt , ''yyyy'') yr 
                                                  FROM (SELECT to_date(''31-DEC-'' 
                                                                                || 
                                                                         (SELECT max(thn) 
                                                                                FROM apps.xxcust_nk_v) , ''DD-MON-YYYY'') - level dt 
                                                                  FROM dual connect BY level <= to_date(''31-DEC-'' 
                                                                                || substr( to_char(trunc(sysdate) , ''MON-RRRR'') , 5 , 4) , ''DD-MON-YYYY'') - to_date(''01-JAN-'' 
                                                                                ||(substr(to_char(trunc(sysdate) , ''MON-RRRR'') , 5 , 4) - 4) , ''DD-MON-YYYY'')) 
                                                  GROUP BY to_char(dt , ''yyyy'') 
                                                  ORDER BY to_char(dt , ''yyyy'') DESC)) tahun , 
                           apps.xxcust_nk_v nk 
                  WHERE tahun.yr = nk.thn(+) 
                  GROUP BY person_id) nk_rata ,
(select person_id, max(effective_end_date) end_date from per_people_f
where current_emp_or_apl_flag=''Y''
group by person_id) term
WHERE 100=100
AND papf.person_id = paaf.person_id 
AND paaf.grade_id = pg.grade_id(+) 
AND pg.grade_definition_id = pgd.grade_definition_id(+) 
AND term.person_id = papf.person_id
AND '''+@EFEKTIF_DATE+''' BETWEEN papf.effective_start_date AND      nvl(papf.effective_end_date , to_date(''31-DEC-4712'' , ''DD-MON-YYYY'')) 
AND paaf.organization_id = haou.organization_id 
AND papf.marital_status = hl2.lookup_code(+) 
AND hl2.enabled_flag(+) = ''Y'' 
AND hl2.lookup_type(+) = ''MAR_STATUS'' 
AND paaf.primary_flag = ''Y'' 
AND ppt.person_type_id = papf.person_type_id 
AND paaf.assignment_status_type_id = st.assignment_status_type_id 
AND paaf.assignment_status_type_id = amd.assignment_status_type_id(+) 
AND paaf.business_group_id + 0 = amd.business_group_id(+) + 0 
AND st.assignment_status_type_id = sttl.assignment_status_type_id 
AND sttl.language = userenv(''LANG'') 
AND amd.ass_status_type_amend_id = amdtl.ass_status_type_amend_id(+) 
AND decode(amdtl.ass_status_type_amend_id , NULL , ''1'' , amdtl.language) = decode(amdtl.ass_status_type_amend_id , NULL , ''1'' , userenv(''LANG'')) 
AND papf.person_id = pac_v.person_id(+) 
AND papf.person_id = pend.person_id(+) 
AND papf.person_id = sanksi.person_id(+) 
AND pqt.attribute1(+) = pend.attribute1 
AND nk_.person_id(+) = papf.person_id 
AND nk_rata.person_id(+) = papf.person_id 
AND nk_data.person_id(+) = papf.person_id 
AND papf.employee_number IS NOT NULL 
AND nvl(floor (months_between( '''+@EFEKTIF_DATE+''' , to_date(pac_v.segment4 , ''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'')) / 12) , 0) = nvl(NULL , nvl(floor(months_between( '''+@EFEKTIF_DATE+''' , to_date(pac_v.segment4 , ''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'')) / 12) , 0)) 
AND nvl(floor (months_between( '''+@EFEKTIF_DATE+''' , to_date(pac_v.segment8 , ''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'')) / 12) , 0) = nvl(NULL , nvl(floor(months_between( '''+@EFEKTIF_DATE+''' , to_date(pac_v.segment8 , ''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'')) / 12) , 0)) 
AND nvl(floor (months_between( '''+@EFEKTIF_DATE+''' , to_date(pac_v.segment7 , ''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'')) / 12) , 0) = nvl(NULL , nvl(floor(months_between( '''+@EFEKTIF_DATE+''' , to_date(pac_v.segment7 , ''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'')) / 12) , 0)) 
AND nvl(floor (months_between( '''+@EFEKTIF_DATE+''' , to_date(pac_v.segment6 , ''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'')) / 12) , 0) = nvl(NULL , nvl(floor(months_between( '''+@EFEKTIF_DATE+''' , to_date(pac_v.segment6 , ''RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'')) / 12) , 0)) 
AND nvl(pqt.NAME , 1) = nvl(NULL , nvl(pqt.NAME , 1))
ORDER BY papf.employee_number , 
         papf.last_name'
```

this stored procedure supposed to returning data from linked server to oracle.
when i execute the variable using EXEC(@SQL_P1+@SQL_P2+@SQL_P3) AT ERP and running the Stored Procedure,it doesn't returning data in rows.
capture

[image: EXEC(@VAR) running]

but when i use SELECT @SQL_P1+@SQL_P2+@SQL_P3 then running the procedure,it returning the query that can be run in SQL ORACLE DEVELOPER.

so what is wrong with it?

Comment: The easiest way to debug dynamic SQL is to `PRINT`/`SELECT` the statement first. Then you can debug that SQL first, and solve the problem before propagating the solution to your SQL that generates the dynamic statement. Often you'll find that the problems are quite simple, such as a typographical error that is difficult to stop in the literal strings, a missing whitespace/linebreak, or leading/trailing delimiters. Taking the time to get the non-dynamic statement working first is really important, as if that doesn't work the dynamic one will have no chance of working correctly.

Comment: We can't run your query, and clearly the query is running (or you would get an error), so there's very little we can do here. I would suggest the problem is you are filtering the data out somewhere, but where, we likely have no idea.

Comment: What does that screenshot has anything to do with your query ? It is not the same thing at all. One is a stored procedure, the other is a big select query

Comment: @Squirrel it was my attempts to run the "big select query" using stored procedure and it not returning data

Comment: @Larnu when i tried to use PRINT,it doesn't return all my query string. when i use SELECT it return all my query string and i can run it normally on oracle sql developer / TOAD

Comment: then you aren't `PRINT`ing/`SELECT`ing the same thing, @DiditPraditya . If `@SomeVariable` has a non-`NULL` value, then `PRINT @SomeVariable` and `SELECT @SomeVariable` will return said value (though may be truncated due to the length of the string).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's solved,i change some parameters with sysdate in the query.
but at some point it only receiving date as a parameters.
idk,as long as it works :)

cheers..
thank you